# Converting TCP/IP traffic to Halfduplex in linux

Tags: network-programming, linux-device-driver

I am developing a custom network driver for a PHY media which doesn't support full duplex mode.

I want to use TCP/IP traffic with this network driver and on top of this half-duplex PHY media.
But TCP/IP traffic can be full duplex. I would like to implement some mechanism/algorithm in this driver so that this custom network driver will convert TCP/IP traffic to Half duplex in linux.

Please let me know if this can be achieved or how to do it.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Is the custom network driver for a custom network? If not, what is it for? What's the overall objective?

Comment: I am developing a custom network driver for a PHY media which doesn't support full duplex mode. Overall objective is I want to use Fullduplex TCP/IP traffic on our Half Duplex PHY media. I want to know how I can manage this in our network driver or any other mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to write a driver which supports full duplex traffic on a card which actually does NOT support the feature...

Well..you must be aware that the networking subsystem is one of the largest subsystems in the kernel and one of the few which actually uses softirqs (because it is always looking at getting scaled appropriately in this day and age of multiprocessers) and still had to resort to some trickery (NAPI) ir order to manage the deluge of interrupt requests generated by the ever increasing rates of the present day media...why im saying all this is because I just would want to remind you of the real life complexities involved in writing a 'regular' network driver, let alone a 'pseudo full duplex' driver.

Now I believe what you pretty much want is to give an illusion of 'full duplexity' to the...TCP/IP stack ( is it ??) i.e your driver is just another full duplex driver and it (any one of this driver's clients, be it the MAC layer or something like ethtool) can go have a ball with it (in terms of dumping & retrieving packets) in the same manner as it does with (and expects results out of) a 'regular full duplex' driver...

So if this is really the case, I wonder what good giving such an illusion might be? Perhaps you are just experimenting? IN any case, TCP is by default full duplex anyways and by using a half duplex media the data rates anyway are a bit lower (although not exactly half) than those obtained by using a full duplex adapter. I don't think it even matters at the higher layers (in terms of functionality) whether the media is full or half duplex (except may be in the MAC layer?) correct me if Im wrong.

There were (and still are) quite a few half duplex media in use currently and as such there are many media which support both full duplex and half duplex traffic..I fail to see how it will affect the clients of the driver (besides lowering the over all data rate as the only tangible effect)...which means you can pretty much look at any netwrk driver in the kernel and see that it has ways to configure the adapter to use either full or half duplex (and the user space can, say ethtool as one of the ways to toggle this...)...

Anyways, you may want to have a look and perhaps take a few tips from MODBus driver (the bus being by default half duplex) [here](http://iatips.wikispaces.com/ModbusRBX).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're relating MAC layer with TCP layer. Duplex mode is a Ethernet domain and it doesn't propagate to IP and not event to TCP, in Ethernet terms duplexity means you can send or receive a MAC frames exclusively at different times (half duplex) or at the same time (full duplex).

The upper layers of the network stack are completely (at least they should) unaware of this process. Consider the following example, you're sending a huge file over the network using FTP, assuming most normal network systems the stack would be FTP/TCP/IP/Ethernet. From FTP perspective you have a virtual session, from TCP you have a virtual pipe, from IP you just know how to reach the end system and from Ethernet perspective you just know how to reach the next node in the network.

TCP doesn't care your packets are chopped during the transmission nor if your packet is delayed within a certain threshold due an incoming packet arriving It only cares to receive a confirmation receipt that the packet made it to the final destination. I hope I can show my point.